# Marketing Cloud Double op-in when importing data via .csv

Tags: marketing-cloud

Does anybody know if its is possible to send out an OPT-IN Mail including OPT-IN link when we add subscriber via a .csv import?

Is there anything like it when you use Web Collect only for .csv uploads?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The default 'Welcome Email' functionality / 'Double-opt in' associated to lists isn't available with imports as far I know. So I think this would have to be custom.

Possible option: Create a Profile Attribute or Data Extension field labeled 'Double opt-in'. Create an email with a link to a landing page that, once loaded, automatically updates this field for that user. Send this email to only the newly imported subscribers.

You can then segment based on the value of this field within the Marketing Cloud to ensure you are only sending to double opted-in users. Also keep in mind whether or not a 'double opt-in' is truly worth it, as I don't believe it's a requirement by any current standards (although maybe outside of North America it is different).

Comment: Thank you @AnonWonderer 

ill will try your mentioned solution.
I got your point that its a "pain" to have a double opt-in in this example.

Bute here in germany it is absolutly mandatory by law to have a Double Opt-In for every email (contact) you want to add to your marketing campaign. :(